# How do you keep your login information private when you push your code to GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I am using a shell script to automate the deployment of my website.
I now want to push the code of this site onto GitHub, and now I am facing the problem that my login details will be publicly accessible if I push the deploy script too. Is there any way of changing or leaving out the file when I push to GitHub? I would still like to keep it under version control.

Comment: I guess, the better way to do such a thing is to keep your private info in separtate file excluded from version control, and somehow load it from the script (if it is shell-script, `source` is perhaps the easiest way to do so).

Comment: Awesome, I'm doing it using `source` now, cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered keeping login information in a separate non versioned file?

login.xml

```
<user>John</user>
<password>Doe</password>
```